# Unable to create a shipment all the SOLine Items to the Shipment Screen (SOShipLine-Manually we are bringing non-stock items to the shipment screen)

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

when we are creating the Shipment “Is-Component” field we added newly in Sales Order Screen  when we checked this field and when we process the shipment in Shipment screen the particular inventory data item is not passing only for checked ” Is component “item , unchecked items of “Is component” item are able to pass to shipment screen .

```
[PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter, Nullable<Int32> actionID, Nullable<DateTime> shipDate, String siteCD, String operation, String ActionName, ActionDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            if (actionID == 1)
            {

            SOShipmentEntry ShipGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
            PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOShipmentEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            ShipGraph.RowInserting.AddHandler<SOShipLine>((sender, e) =>
            {
                foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    ShipGraph.Transactions.Current = PXSelect<SOShipLine, Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base, line.InventoryID, line.OrderNbr);
                    SOShipLine ShipLine = new SOShipLine();

                    SOLineExt NonStklnExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
                    if (ShipGraph.Transactions.Current == null)
                    {
                        //if (NonStklnExt.UsrIsComponent == true || NonStklnExt.UsrIsComponent == false || NonStklnExt.UsrInvFlag == true || NonStklnExt.UsrInvFlag == false || NonStklnExt.UsrStkInventoryID == null || NonStklnExt.UsrStkInventoryID != null)
                        //{
                        ShipLine.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;
                        ShipLine.TranDesc = line.TranDesc;
                        // }
                        ShipGraph.Transactions.Insert(ShipLine);
                    }



                }
                Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
            });
        });
        }
        return baseMethod(adapter, actionID, shipDate, siteCD, operation, ActionName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that these items are added based on the flag, not always added based on the item. If that is the case, I would check the Require Shipment flag on the Non-Stock item to have it automatically added.

I would go at this by overriding the SOShipmentEntry CreateShipment function, rather than the SOShipLine Insert handler. Ensure you override the one that has the QuickProcessFlow.

From there, I would search for the initial order and order lines as you are doing after the shipment is created. Your logic is checking if the flags are checked or unchecked on the line, and should be updated. For example, if you wanted to find all items that are not on the shipment that have the component checked that are not auto added based on the NonStockShip flag, I would go at it like this:

```
public delegate void CreateShipmentDelegate(SOOrder order, Nullable<Int32> SiteID, Nullable<DateTime> ShipDate, Nullable<Boolean> useOptimalShipDate, String operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list, ActionFlow quickProcessFlow);
[PXOverride]
public void CreateShipment(SOOrder order, Nullable<Int32> SiteID, Nullable<DateTime> ShipDate, Nullable<Boolean> useOptimalShipDate, String operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list, ActionFlow quickProcessFlow, CreateShipmentDelegate baseMethod)
{
    baseMethod(order, SiteID, ShipDate, useOptimalShipDate, operation, list, quickProcessFlow);

    if (order == null)
        return; //do not process for shipments that did not have an order sent for some reason

    //get all lines for non-stockitems that are not flagged to be shipped that have the component checked
    var SalesOrderLines = PXSelectJoin<
        SOLine, 
        InnerJoin<InventoryItem, 
            On<SOLine.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>,
        Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>, 
            And<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>,                     
            And<InventoryItem.nonStockShip, Equal<False>,
            And<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<False>,
            And<SOLineExt.usrIsComponent, Equal<True>>>>>>>
        .Select(Base, order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType);

    foreach(SOLine SalesOrderLine in SalesOrderLines)
    {
        //double check that they were not added.... and match the orig line nbr
        var ShipmentLinesForItem = PXSelect<
            SOShipLine, 
            Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>,
                And<SOShipLine.shipmentType, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentType>>, 
                And<SOShipLine.inventoryID, Equal<Required<SOShipLine.inventoryID>>, 
                And<SOShipLine.origLineNbr, Equal<Required<SOShipLine.origLineNbr>>>>>>>
            .Select(Base, SalesOrderLine.InventoryID, SalesOrderLine.LineNbr);
        if (ShipmentLinesForItem.Count == 0)
        {
            //create your shipment lines for these items
            SOShipLine ShipmentLine = new SOShipLine();
            //set fields required. See function SOOrderEntry.CreateShipmentFromSchedules for examples of fields that should be set.
            Base.Transactions.Insert(ShipmentLine);
        }
    }
}
```